# Why is saveXML creating `&#13;` linebreaks?

Tags: php, xml, dom, domdocument, line-breaks

I am using this:

```
foreach ($paragraph->childNodes as $child) {
        $value .= $paragraph->ownerDocument->saveHTML($child);
    }
```

The problem is that in my `$value` I have `&#13;` there where in the original document I have a linebreak.

Here is one part of the source HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 12 (filtered)">
      <title>SomeTitle</title>
  </head>
  <body lang=EN-US link=blue vlink=purple>
    <div class=WordSection1>
    <p class=3abstract><b>Abstract:</b> Five new anthranilic acid derivatives.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Did you faced this before?

Comment: Sure, I will edit my anwer immediately

Comment: I see the generator is "Microsoft Word 12". M$ prints new lines as `\r\n`. Try normalizing them with `preg_replace('~\R~u', "\n", $html)`, then load the html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&#13;` is the decimal HTML entity representation of "carriage return", so it's perfectly fine  in the output.

To output the actual carriage return character, try setting the output encoding of the parent document to UTF-8: `$paragraph->ownerDocument->encoding = 'UTF-8'`.

Answer (score 0):

Alf failed to clarify *how* to define the encoding which is done via `new DOMDocument`. This in turn removes the `&#13;` numeric entities:

```
   $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');//<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   $dom->loadHTML($xml);
   $xml = $dom->saveXml($dom);
```

Based on his code I was getting errors like:

> Attempt to modify property 'ownerDocument' of non-object

Alternatively you can use the following string replacement:

```
$xml = str_ireplace("\r\n", "\n", $xml);
```